# How do I open a folder with AppleScript in the current finder window?

Tags: applescript, finder

I know `tell application "Finder" to open POSIX file "/folder/path/"` will open a *new* finder window, how can I open a folder in the **current** finder window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the target of the front Finder window to (POSIX file "/folder/path/")
end tell
```